# Wayland keybinding for raise-or-lower not working for some keys

Tags: shortcut-keys, wayland, gnome-control-center

I am running Ubuntu 22.04.03/Wayland.

Using gnome-tweaks I have set Window Focus to *"Focus on Hover"* but without *"Raise Windows When Focused"*. I want to be able to hover over a window which is partially covered by another and use a keybinding to force it to raise, and likewise if it is already raised I want it to go to the bottom of the window stack so I can see what's behind it. This is what's known in dconf Window Manager functionality as *"raise-or-lower".*

**I have created a key binding via gnome-control-center for org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings.raise-or-lower, however it is not doing anything**. I checked in dconf-editor and verified the keysym using xev (it's a special key on my keyboard known as SunFront), and the value is set correctly.
Oddly, although the binding was entered correctly through gnome-control-center it is reported incorrectly by it ("0x10" - correct keysym as reported by dconf-editor and xev is 0x1005ff71).
I do find that this works if I bind it to other more standard keys, however (and keynames are reported correctly).

I have not found any bug reports on this. Does anyone know what might be happening here? Or have a pointer to where such a bug should be filed?

Comment: Somebody voted my question down without comment. I'd sure like to understand why. I did my best to provide all the relevant detail and highlighted the crux of my question with bold text to make it easy to digest. I did significant diligence to investigate, identify and communicate the issue. It's not a duplicate and is well-formed. So what's the beef please?

Comment: I have subsequently found references to "limitations" regarding what keys can be used as shortcuts by dconf, but I can't find any actual description of what those limitations may be. In any case I used to be able to bind that key for that function on X11 so this seems like a Wayland issue rather than a dconf issue.

Comment: For me, this works. The problem is likely in your keybinding - you do not disclose in your post to what you have set that keybinding, so there is little else we can test.

Comment: But I did state it. The keysym is 0x1005ff71 (a special key on my keyboard which xev reports as 'SunFront'), which I bound to raise-or-lower. It works fine if I set it to Pause, but not SunFront. The keysym is reported correctly by dconf-editor, but not gnome-control-center (which reports it as 0x10).

Comment: Is this what you entered in dconf-editor? That may not a valid specifier.

Comment: No, as I stated in my post I typed the key into gnome-control-center. This is what dconf-editor reports, and it is correct because that's what xev prints for the keysym when I press the key.